# Android ViewBinding handle fragment null after onDestroy

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I'm implementing `ViewBinding` and according to Google docs we should do this:

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

....

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

We are forcing `binding` to be non-null but we may end up with a situation like this:

```
binding.itemView.post {
    // when post is called, fragment is still available but when the runnable run's fragment isn't available.
    binding.itemView.setText="......"
}
```

We could let the getter return null but in this case, we would need to `binding?.` all over the place.

How can this be handled so that `binding.itemView.setText="......"` does not crash the app?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do that.  Having something be valid only until onDestroy  like that seems a great way for race conditions to occur.  Especially if you have asynchronous processing.  Instead I'd just use _binding and have my code do `_binding?.itemView.text=""`